# Visual Studio и онлайн компилятор выводят разные ответы на одну и ту же задачу

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Задача состояла в том, чтобы вывести одномерный массив, перед этим  уменьшив (с помощью рекурсии) его четные элементы на значение суммы индексов нечетных элементов (сумму также нужно найти с помощью рекурсии) и вывести полученный одномерный массив.

Сначала я написал код в VS и он вывел мне неправильный ответ (input: (len 5) 12 10 3 4 5 -> output: 1 -1 3 -7 5)). Чётные элементы должны уменьшаться на 6, так как индекс числа 3 это 2, а числа 5 - 4. То есть их сумма 6, но никак не 11, как мне насчитал VS. Я долго не мог понять в чём проблема, пока тупо не скопировал код и не вставил его в онлайн компилятор (onlinegdb), который показал мне уже верный ответ (input (len 5) 12 10 3 4 5 -> output: 6 4 3 -2 5). Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int *a, int n, int i) {
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    if (a[i] % 2 != 0) return sum(a, n - 1, i + 1) + i;
    else return sum(a, n - 1, i + 1);
}
void decrease(int* a, int n, int i, int x) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0) 
            a[i] -= x;
    decrease(a, n - 1, i + 1, x);
    }
}


int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    decrease(a, n, 0, sum(a, n, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Рекурсивные функции выходят за границы массива, т.к. обрабатывают на один элемент больше, чем есть в массиве. `decrease(a, n, 0, sum(a, n, 0));` -> `decrease(a, n-1, 0, sum(a, n-1, 0));`

Comment: Привыкайте для размеров массивов использовать не int, а size_t. Кроме случаев, когда размер массива явно ограничен, а его максимум представим в меньшем целом числовом типе. Но и тогда привыкайте юзать беззнаковые целые числовые типы. И динамическую память надо освобождать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вопрос полностью правильно ответил wololo.
От себя пару моментов. У вас `n` - это количество элементов в массиве. Почему рассматриваете её как индекс элемента и сравниваете с `0`?
Хотя идея в принципе-то верная! В рекурсивных функциях переменная i - излишняя. Зачем вам отдельная переменная под индекс? Вы же передаете рекурсивно уменьшая значение `n` - чем не индекс?

```
int sum(int *a, int n) 
{
    if (n < 0) 
        return 0;
    cout << n << " ";
    if (a[n] % 2 != 0) 
        return sum(a, n - 1) + n;
    else 
        return sum(a, n - 1);
}
```

Используя `n` в качестве индекса при доступе к массиву вы точно будете помнить, что она изменяется от количество эл-ов - 1 до 0. Заодно уменьшили количество аргументов в рекурсивных функциях, что уменьшит заполнение отнюдь не резинового стека.
Ну и как всегда - если выделили память через `new[]`, то освобождайте её через `delete[]`. Не стоит привыкать к автоматическому освобождению при завершении программы.